# "A is followed by B." What's the order?

Tags: word-order

So the English class teacher is teaching IEEE referencing style, and we have something like this as an example:

> Chan [1] claims that...

The teacher said:

> The referencing number **is followed by** the author's last name.

Wait... I thought "A is followed by B" means B follows A, that means A comes first, B comes next.

Has the teacher made an obvious mistake, or is it my fault? (Could I have misheard that?)

Comment: Either is possible: you may have misheard, or the statement made was wrong. Certainly the number follows the name in your example.

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “followed by” and “is followed by”?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/49960/5365)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a chance the teacher was explaining how the reference is formatted at the **end** of the paper. From an [IEEE citation reference guide](http://www.ieee.org/documents/ieeecitationref.pdf):

> *Examples*:
>   [1] B. Klaus and P. Horn, *Robot Vision*. Cambridge, MA: MIT Press, 1986.
>   [2] L. Stein, “Random patterns,” in *Computers and You*, J. S. Brake, Ed. New York: Wiley, 1994, pp. 55-70.
>   [3] R. L. Myer, “Parametric oscillators and nonlinear materials,” in *Nonlinear Optics*, vol. 4, P. G. Harper and B. S. Wherret, Eds. San Francisco, CA: Academic, 1977, pp. 47-160.

Once you're at the end of the paper (as opposed to in the body of the text), the referencing number is followed by the author's name – just like the teacher said.

<sub>But your understanding of *is followed by* is correct.</sub>

Comment: I really need to read up on the fundamental insolvability of determining simultaneity between unrelated reference frames. :)

Comment: @tchrist: I think there's an expression for that – *great minds think alike*?

Answer (score 3):

A normal use has the name following the reference number when used in the footnote or bibliography.

> Chan [1] claims that bound morphemes form an independent class in all PIE-derived languages.
>
> 1. Jeremiah P. Chan in “Rethinking morphemic class assignment in Proto-Indo-European” in *Proceeding of the American Linguistic Society*, June 2015 (Boston).